# I'm trying to learn how to use link lists

Tags: c

I'm trying to learn how to use link lists in the place of arrays, and I feel like i'm understanding the concept but I can't my program to run...  Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct linkList{
    float val;
    struct linkList *next;
    };

int main()
{
    struct linkList n1,n2,n3,*start;

    n1.val=5.5;
    n2.val=6.6;
    n3.val=7.7;
    start=&n1;

    n1.next=&n2;
    n2.next=&n3;
    n3.next=0;


    while(start.next!=0){
        printf("%f",start.val);
        start=start.next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to use the arrow operator `->` when using a pointer like `start`.  You also should end printing operations like `printf` with a newline somewhere, or otherwise worry about separating the numbers.

Comment: `while(start!=0){ printf("%f ",start->val); start=start->next; }`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem resolved. Please see the below C code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct linkList
{
    float val;
    struct linkList *next;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct linkList n1, n2, n3, *start;

    n1.val = 5.5;
    n2.val = 6.6;
    n3.val = 7.7;
    start = &n1;

    n1.next = &n2;
    n2.next = &n3;
    n3.next = 0;


    while(start->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("%f \n",start->val);
        start=start->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct node {
int data;
int key;
struct node *next;
};

struct node *head = NULL;
struct node *current = NULL;

//display the list
void printList() {
struct node *ptr = head;
printf("\n[ ");

 //start from the beginning
 while(ptr != NULL) {
  printf("(%d,%d) ",ptr->key,ptr->data);
  ptr = ptr->next;
 }

 printf(" ]");
}

 //insert link at the first location
   void insertFirst(int key, int data) {
  //create a link
   struct node *link = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    link->key = key;
    link->data = data;

     //point it to old first node
     link->next = head;

    //point first to new first node
    head = link;
    }

    int main(){

    insertFirst(1,10);
    insertFirst(2,20);
    insertFirst(3,30);
    insertFirst(4,1);
    insertFirst(5,40);
    insertFirst(6,56); 
    printList();
     return 0;
    }
```